# iOs safari audio tag restarting playback

Tags: html, ios7, html5-audio

As stated in the header. On iOs 7, iPhone 4, in safari, when I play an audio element it restarts playback of the file after a while (irregular timing). So the user can't listen to the audio file till the end since the audio controls aren't even shown, just a play/pause button.

Has anyone encountered such a behavior?

P.S.
The files are good. Playing them on desktop machine on chrome/firefox works as intended, listening till the end no problem. Same goes on android/google chrome.
Haven't tested on other iOs versions.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? I run into this issue as well....

Comment: Nah, Iphone 4 is long gone from the pedestal ;)
Not sure what I did then, I think the task was given to someone else, and in the end I think it was a headers issue.. But don't take my word for it.